# jQuery ajax data return to json controller the value is null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

[image]

I don't know why when jQuery ajax data is sent to the controller, value shows null, such as the picture shows success function (data) error. Get data empty。
When the code was first tested, only one data was null, but later it showed that all data values were null.
What part of the code am I having a problem with?

```js
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#table1").click('#SelectBtn', function () {
                      
                    var bid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    var status = $("#enumId option:selected").val();
                    var mess = $('#message-text').val();
                    
                    $('#Submit').click('#enumId', function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                url: '@Url.Action("saveStatus")',
                                data: { id: bid, status:$("#enumId option:selected").val(), Remark:$('#message-text').val() },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    bid.url(data);
                                    status.val('');
                                    mess.val('');
                                    alert("Success, sent data to controller");

                                }, error: function (data) {
                                    alert("Error: " + data);
                                },
                            })
                        })

                    })      
            })
        </script>
```

```css
     public JsonResult saveStatus(int id, string status, string Remark)
            {
                int approvalId;

                if (id == 0)
                {
                    var staff = db.Staffs.Where(s => s.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                    RequestForApproval ap = new RequestForApproval
                    {
                        RequestToStaffId = staff.Id,
                        RequestDate = DateTime.Now,


                    };
                    db.RequestForApprovals.Add(ap);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    approvalId = ap.Id;
                }
                else
                {
                    approvalId = id;
                }
                Status stat = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), status);

                ApprovalStatus temp = new ApprovalStatus
                {
                    Id = approvalId,
                    Remark = Remark,
                    Status = stat,
                    AddDate = DateTime.Now

                };
                db.ApprovalStatuses.Add(temp);
                db.SaveChanges();
                var df = db.ApprovalStatuses.Where(s => s.Id == approvalId).ToList();
                return Json(df);
            }
```

```html
    <table class="table" id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Staff Fname
            </th>
            <th>
                RequestDate
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.GetReApproval)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="~/Reimbursements/GetOtherDetails/@item.ReimbursementId">@item.ReimbursementId</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.StaffName

                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.RequestDate
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.RequerForApprovalId" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.RequerForApprovalId" data-target="#exampleModal" id="SelectBtn">Select</button>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="Title">Select and Confirm</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="Reid" />
                                            @Html.DropDownList("ApprovalStatus", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info", id = "enumId" })
                                            @*@Html.DropDownList("Index", ViewBag.DropDownList as SelectList,null, new { @class = "btn btn-info",@id="DropDownList" })*@
                                        </div>
                                        <hr />

                                        <div class="form-group" style="visibility:visible" id="remarktext">
                                            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Remark:</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                                        </div>

                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirme</button>*@
                                    @*<button data-id="@item.ReimbursementId" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddRequestForApproval","Reimbursements")'">Submit</button>*@
                                    <button data-rid="@item.ReimbursementId" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" >Submit</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="reset" id="Clear">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your c# code if you're receiving the values you're passing?

Comment: Oh okay, read the description just now, all the values were null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a viewmodel or a class to be able to bind those values in the controller.

```
// new model
public class JsonReceiveModel{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Status {get;set;}
    public string Remark {get;set;}
}

// modifed to use model.Id, model.Status, model.Remark
public JsonResult saveStatus(JsonReceiveModel model) {
    int approvalId;

    if (model.Id == 0) {
        var staff = db.Staffs.Where(s => s.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        RequestForApproval ap = new RequestForApproval {
            RequestToStaffId = staff.Id,
                RequestDate = DateTime.Now,

        };
        db.RequestForApprovals.Add(ap);
        db.SaveChanges();
        approvalId = ap.Id;
    } else {
        approvalId = id;
    }
    Status stat = (Status) Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), status);

    ApprovalStatus temp = new ApprovalStatus {
        Id = approvalId,
            Remark = model.Remark,
            Status = model.Status,
            AddDate = DateTime.Now

    };
    db.ApprovalStatuses.Add(temp);
    db.SaveChanges();
    var df = db.ApprovalStatuses.Where(s => s.Id == approvalId).ToList();
    return Json(df);
}
```

Then include `contentType: 'application/json'` in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '@Url.Action("saveStatus")',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        id: bid,
        status: $("#enumId option:selected").val(),
        Remark: $('#message-text').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        bid.url(data);
        status.val('');
        mess.val('');
        alert("Success, sent data to controller");

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Error: " + data);
    },
})
```